# How do I reference a pair of attributes in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

We have a couple of tables (in oracle sql):

```
CREATE TABLE programs(
        prog_name VARCHAR2(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        prog_abbr VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL

);
CREATE TABLE students (
        student_id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
        student_program VARCHAR2(20) REFERENCES programs (prog_name)
);
CREATE TABLE branches (
        branch_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
        prog_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL REFERENCES programs(prog_name),         
        PRIMARY KEY(branch_name, prog_name)
);
```

Table branches is a weak entity of program so we have a composite key.

We need to create a new table containing the branch and program of every student:

```
CREATE TABLE student_branches(
          student_id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES students(student_id),
          branch_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
          prog_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);
```

**Problem 1**

How do we make it so that we can't enter a `student_id` into `student_branches` that doesn't belong to their own program?
Say we have a student:

```
INSERT INTO students VALUES ('1', 'Computer Engineering');
```

Then we should **not** be able to enter

```
INSERT INTO student_branches VALUES ('1','Some Branch' 'Electrical Engineering');
```

I want to write something like:

```
(student_id, prog_name) REFERENCES students (student_id, student_program)
```

to catch that constraint but oracle doesn't accept it.

**Problem 2**

Similarly we shouldn't be able to enter a branch that does not belong to the program the student is currently enrolled in, for example if we have a branch "Software Engineering" that belongs to the program "Computer Engineering":

```
INSERT INTO branches VALUES ('1', 'Software', 'Computer Engineering');
```

We shouldn't be able to enter a student enrolled in some other program to read the branch software engineering:

```
INSERT INTO student_branches VALUES ('1', 'Software', 'Computer Engineering');
```

We solved this problem like this:

```
ALTER TABLE student_branches
    add foreign key(branch_name, prog_name) references branches(branch_name, prog_name);
```

But is this a correct way to solve it? Can the first problem be solved in a similar way?

Comment: Thanks for providing the table scripts, that's very helpful! Could you update the question to also include all the insert statements that produces the scenarios you're talking about in both problems, please? (I know you've provided some insert statements, but not for every table involved.)

Comment: If as student can be part of more than one program, Step 1 is to drop the student_program field from the student_table.  Plus you might want to look at creating some sort of relationship between programs and branches.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it the same way; but there isn't a matching primary key so you will also need to create a unique key on the students table for the foreign key to reference:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
  student_id      NUMBER(10)   CONSTRAINT students__si__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  student_program VARCHAR2(50) CONSTRAINT students__sp__fk REFERENCES programs (prog_name),
  CONSTRAINT students__si_sp__u UNIQUE ( student_id, student_program )
);

CREATE TABLE student_branches(
  student_id  NUMBER(10)   CONSTRAINT student_branches__si__pk PRIMARY KEY
                           CONSTRAINT student_branches__si__fk REFERENCES students(student_id),
  branch_name VARCHAR2(50) CONSTRAINT student_branches__bn__nn NOT NULL,
  prog_name   VARCHAR2(50) CONSTRAINT student_branches__pn__nn NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT student_branches__bn_pn__fk FOREIGN KEY ( branch_name, prog_name ) REFERENCES branches ( branch_name, prog_name ),
  CONSTRAINT student_branches__si_pn__fk FOREIGN KEY ( student_id, prog_name ) REFERENCES students ( student_id, student_program )
);
```